# Prism and Xamarin.Forms: IApplicationLifecycle

Tags: xamarin, prism

I have a viewmodel that inherits from BindableBase and implements IApplicationLifecycle. However, IApplicationLifecycle.OnResume() and IApplicationLifecycle.OnSleep() is never called on neither iOS nor android.

How do you use IApplicationLifecycle? I cant seem to find any documentation for it. Thanks in advance!

In my App.xaml.cs i have:

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");
```

and my MainPage.xaml looks like this:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrismApp.Views;assembly=PrismApp"
         xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
         x:Class="PrismApp.Views.MainPage"
         Title="MainPage">

<TabbedPage.Children>
    <local:APage Icon="tabicon_mapspage.png" />
    <local:BPage Icon="tabicon_profilepage.png" />
    <local:CPage Icon="tabicon_statuspage.png" />
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

Finally my MainPageViewModel looks like this:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase, IApplicationLifecycle
{
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }
    public void OnResume()
    {
        var debug = 42;
    }

    public void OnSleep()
    {
        var debug = 42;
    }
}
```

I have put a minimal project of it here: https://github.com/RandomStuffAndCode/PrismApp

Comment: You'll need to provide much more information about the page structure of your app, and your current navigation stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in a TabbedPage the IApplicationAware methods are only being invoked on the TabbedPage.CurrentPage (SelectedTab), as that is the current active page.

By the way, you can change this behavior by overriding the OnResume and OnSleep methods in your app class to achieve your goal.  Use the existing code as a guide: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/PrismApplicationBase.cs#L171